# Ошибка 1064 mysql: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

Помогите найти ошибку в базе.

[image: mysql]

Выдает ошибку №1064

> # 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`id()`)))) ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 1

какое правильное название ключа?

Comment: а чем вас не устроило написать PRIMARY KEY (`id`) и всё?

Comment: Зачем так много скобок тут `(id()))))` ?

Comment: А слабо запрос текстом было вставить?

Comment: просто (id) не помогло. все равно ошибка вылазит

Comment: @GavrenkoKaterina а без ENGINE = InnoDB попробуйте еще PRIMARY KEY (`id`); так

Comment: Добавьте код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не изображения. Для этого используйте ссылку «[edit]», расположенную под метками вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При указании первичного ключа в конце создания таблицы, достаточно ключ указать в скобках и всё.

Пример

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    P_Id int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Как видите указано `PRIMARY KEY` и один раз в скобках имя первичного ключа `(P_Id)`. Аналогично нужно сделать и вам.

И еще совет, писать запрос в несколько строк (как в примере выше), чтоб визуально отделить что где находится, а не делать кучу малу.
И это как минимум поможет при ошибках в запросе.